# What is the time complexity of this permutation algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

The algorithm is as follows:

```
void permutation(String str) {
     permutation(str, "");
}

void permutation(String str, String prefix) {
    if ( st r.length() == e) {
         System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
       for (int i = j; i < str.length(); i++) {
           String rem = str.substring(e, i) + str.substring ( i + 1);
           permutation(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
       }
   }
}
```

Computing the total number of function calls for input size n, we have

$$\sum_{i=0}^n n!/i! = e (n! - Γ(n + 1) + Γ(n + 1, 1))
$$

So we end up with:
$$
O(e (n! - Γ(n + 1) + Γ(n + 1, 1)))
$$
$$
O(n! - Γ(n + 1) + Γ(n + 1, 1))
$$

What I would like to know is how I can simplify this further?

Comment: You can use [Sterling's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). There is also an approximation for $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it like this:
$$
A_n=\sum_{i=0}^n n!/i! = 
n!\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 1/i! -
\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} 1/i!\right).
$$
Neglecting the subtrahend and using the exponential series we get an upper bound:
$$
A_n\leq n!\left(e^1 -0\right)=n!\cdot e.
$$
Again we use the exponential series and some estimates for a lower bound:
$$
A_n\geq
n!\left(e^1 -
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 1/(i!\cdot (n+1)!)\right)=
$$
$$
n!\left(e -
\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 1/i!\right)=
n!\left(e -
\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\cdot e\right)=
$$
$$
n!\cdot e-\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\cdot e\geq
n!\cdot e-e.
$$
Upper and lower bound essentially match and [Sterling's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) yields:
$$
A_n\sim e\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n.
$$